# How to convert RTF file to HTML in native Javascript code (no frameworks)?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, rtf

I am trying to convert a .rtf file to an HTML file so in can be displayed on a mobile device in web view. I have seen a solution but it is either in a different language or requires the use of modules; however, I cannot use modules for my situation.

Thank you.

Comment: You need just parse source RTF as per the [specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725) and then build up HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert the RTF file on the server side before making an HTTP request for the HTML website. You will have to decide how you want the RTF to be formatted in the HTML document.